# Arch os-prober won't find Windows 10 on different disk

Tags: arch-linux, grub, uefi

Ok so I have read similar questions but I haven't been able to solve my problem so far.
I have just installed an Arch in a SSD (located on `/dev/sdc`) and I have a Windows 10 on another SSD (`/dev/sda`).

My problem is that when executing grub config (`grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub.d/grub.cfg`) and having enabled `os-prober`, it still won't find the Windows 10 entry.

The output of `fdisk -l` is:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 223.57 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Disk model: INTEL SSDSCKKW24
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xd67b45de

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048   1026047   1024000   500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         1026048 467744983 466718936 222.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       467746816 468856831   1110016   542M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE


Disk /dev/sdb: *Omitted* 


Disk /dev/sdc: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 870
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: E2F762F9-0255-497D-934E-0B8DF1009AD8

Device        Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdc1      2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sdc2   1050624  34605055  33554432    16G Linux swap
/dev/sdc3  34605056 976773134 942168079 449.3G Linux filesystem
```

How could I fix it so that os-prober detects my Windows 10 system?

**Edit**

As some answers to similar questions suggested, I already tried installing `ntfs-3g`, mounting the Windows partitions and re-running `grub-mkconfig` but it still won't detect the system.

Comment: Your Windows is a legacy installation and not bootable from UEFI. You may convert your Windows disk from MBR to GPT including an ESP partition using Microsoft's [mbr2gpt.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/mbr-to-gpt) tool (see [How to Convert Windows 10 from Legacy BIOS to UEFI without Data Loss](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/81502-convert-windows-10-legacy-bios-uefi-without-data-loss.html)) or you could reinstall Windows in UEFI mode.